# Adding a UITableView in a UIviewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` (ViewControllerA), and in this `UIViewController` I would like to add a `UITableView` subview that occupies part of the screen (named `TableLoadGroupMembersViewController`). I have already created the class for the `UITableView`, called `TableLoadGroupMembersViewController`.

In `ViewControllerA.h` I have imported `TableLoadGroupMembersViewController` in the following way:

```
#import "TableLoadGroupMembersViewController.h"
```

In `ViewcontrollerA.m` I want to create the `UITableView` through code when a button is pressed. I would like the `UITableView` to load the content from `TableLoadGroupMembersViewController`. How can I set the `UITableView` to read the information of the `TableLoadGroupMembersViewController`?

I tried in this way:

```
UITableView* tableVIEW = [[UITableView alloc]init];
TableLoadGroupMembersViewController* tableDelegate = [[TableLoadGroupMembersViewController     alloc] init];
[tableVIEW setDelegate:tableDelegate];
[tableVIEW setDataSource:tableDelegate];

[self.view addSubview:tableVIEW];
```

But it makes the app crash. How should I do it?

EDIT:

This is the error given:

```
0x387209b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi   ....  Thread 1 EXE Bad access
```

Comment: do you have a crash log? have you added all needed methods for datasource / delegate?

Comment: When you assign data source to your tableview, its methods get called. The error you posted does not give any idea. Post code in your UITableViewDataSource methods.

Comment: There is no code yet, its just a template added from New in Xcode, and as type I have put UItableViewController

Comment: before voting down the question please justify :( It seems a reasonable question to me

Comment: do you set a valid (initialized) instance of your `TableLoadGroupMembersViewController` as datasource for the `tableVIEW`?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean.... I do do like this UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

Answer (score 1):

a UITableView does not retain its dataSource or delegate, those are only assigned.

So if you use ARC your `TableLoadGroupMembersViewController` instance gets deallocated when you exit the method were you create the tableView. After the instance gets deallocated dataSource and delegate point to an invalid memory address (because their @property is `assign` and not `weak`)

You can make `TableLoadGroupMembersViewController* tableDelegate` a strong instance variable, then it won't get deallocated.

Something like this.

```
// .h
@property (strong, nonatomic) TableLoadGroupMembersViewController* tableDelegate; 

// .m

UITableView* tableVIEW = [[UITableView alloc]init];
TableLoadGroupMembersViewController* tableDelegate = [[TableLoadGroupMembersViewController     alloc] init];
self.tableDelegate = tableDelegate;
[tableVIEW setDelegate:tableDelegate];
[tableVIEW setDataSource:tableDelegate];

[self.view addSubview:tableVIEW];
```

Comment: actually I have encountered a problem. It seems that the code in TableLoadGroupMembersViewController is not called since NSLogging anyware (even in the view did load) gives no result